# How do you get straw in Medieval Dynasty?

Tags: medieval-dynasty

How do you get straw in Medieval Dynasty?  It dumps me into a village and tells me I need straw to build my house, but I can't find any straw in the village.

Answer (score 0):

To get straw in Medieval Dynasty, you can either:

- Harvest reeds by the river. Reed is a plant you can only find alongside rivers, and it’s fairly plentiful. Each time you harvest Reed, you’ll obtain anywhere between one to two pieces of straw.
- Steal hay from the village. When you start the game, go to the nearest village, approach the open straws, and hold down the “E” key.